# how to change the Slider's thumb Material Component Android with image?

Tags: android, slider, material-design

I am trying to use the slider in Material Design component, but stuck for styling the thumb.
My design requirement needs shadow surrounding the thumb.
From the documentation only show how to change the background thumb.
Is it possible to change the thumb with image?

Comment: it is not possible at the time writing this comment. a feature request was submitted on Material Component's GitHub on July 2020: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1522
But it is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment it's implemented in the beta version.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/17da000a295a4a2554b603940ce014ff6a18da45

Edited.
Methods added in the beta version:

```
setCustomThumbDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable)

setCustomThumbDrawable(@DrawableRes int drawableResId)

setCustomThumbDrawablesForValues(@NonNull @DrawableRes int... customThumbDrawableResIds)

setCustomThumbDrawablesForValues(@NonNull Drawable... customThumbDrawables)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31506257)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to currently set the thumb icon on xml, but by using binding.slider.setCustomThumbDrawable(/* drawable resource */) it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Changing thumb icon is possible to implement with Seekbar android just use `android:thumb="@drawable/yourIcon"`. But i don't think MDC Slider have new ways to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Create your drawable and use:

```
 android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
```

Comment: there is no android:thumb, which one to choose? android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="" or android:scrollbarThumbVertical="", but I have tried that as well, still not working

Comment: as of time of writing, this answer is wrong: there is no such tag for MDC Slider. A feature request was made on the project's GitHub, please see my comment on the question.